# Changing the timescale on the review page

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, review

As a suggestion, while on many other parts of the site it makes sense that the month is defined by the calendar month, for reviewing, this is unhelpful.

When looking at the late answers this month, there was a grand total of one, since it is barely into day of the month. When one changes to year of course, they are flooded.

As such, I would like to suggest changing the options to the past 30 days, 7 days, etc, or at least making that an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already the case, the time filter on review is past 30 days, 7 days ... etc..

I think I had it in the tooltip.